# How to force --help command to execute in run method in Oclif

Tags: oclif

My requirement is quite simple. I want to execute help command when a user executes a specific command without enough arguments.

async run() {
    if (!args.name) {
      this.log(`please provide a project name.`)
       // help ()
    }
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some documentation searching, I found the answer:

```
if (!args.name) {
      this.log(`please provide a project name.`)
      **await Build.run(['--help'])**   
}
```